# I have 3 svelte components. Comp App which imports Comp One and Comp Two. How can Two call a function in One?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I have 3 svelte components.  Comp App which imports Comp One and Comp Two. How can Two call a function in One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could export a function from `Comp1` that you get a reference to in `App` and pass down to `Comp2` as a prop.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/741ffa9ed1714ac1adae20dc477a6204?version=3.12.1))**

```html
<!-- Comp1.svelte -->
<script>
  export function foo() {
    alert('function in Comp1');
  }
</script>

<!-- Comp2.svelte -->
<script>
  export let onClick;
</script>

<button on:click="{onClick}">
  Click me
</button>

<!-- App.svelte -->
<script>
  import Comp1 from './Comp1.svelte';
  import Comp2 from './Comp2.svelte';

  let comp1;
</script>

<Comp1 bind:this="{comp1}" />
<Comp2 onClick="{() => comp1.foo()}" />
```